# Three.JS instance can't be re-created

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to destroy (or destruct or dispose) an 'instance' of Three.JS using this:

Full example: https://jsfiddle.net/v7oLzs4m/58/

```
function kill() {
  const rendererDomWas = renderer.domElement;
  renderer.dispose();
  controls.dispose();
  renderer = scene = camera = controls = null;
  document.body.removeChild( rendererDomWas );
  shouldRender = false;
}

function animate() {
  if(!shouldRender) {return} // no more requesting animation frames if 'shouldRender' is false
  frameID = window.requestAnimationFrame( animate );
  renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

*(i.e. disposing, setting references to null, and stopping the draw loop from `touching` renderer while `shouldRender` is `false`)*

It appears to work at first (The renderer content stops showing) but when I re-create the instance, it never comes back.

It's as if something is still... holding onto the GLContext which prevents it from being invoked again.

Why can't I re-create a new instance of Three.JS?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this works (since I was already doing this in my Fiddle...)

But it turns out the secret ingredient (for me) to letting Three.JS get GC'd/disposed is this:

```
window.cancelAnimationFrame(frameID);
```

I suppose that this stops the render function from being stored in the hardware-level draw loop, which holds references to GLContext (and the chain)

**The GC can't ever happen unless the 'loop is broken'**

(Correct me if I'm wrong please)